# Python - Stop all ThreadPoolExecutor futures if one fails

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency

### Summary:

When running multiple threads concurrently with `ThreadPoolExecutor` and an exception is raised in one of them, the remaining threads continue execution.

Is there a way to stop all other still-running threads if an exception is raised by one of them?

### Code:

This demonstrative script shows that tasks `t1` and `t3` continue running even though the task `t2` fails early:

```py
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
import time


def foo(name):
    print("Started task: " + name)
    if name == "t2":
        raise Exception("Forced fail")
    for i in range(5):
        print("Running task: " + name)
        time.sleep(1)
    return "Completed task: " + name


with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t1"))
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t2"))
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t3"))

    for future in futures:
        print(future.result())
```

### Attempt using wait()

I tried using `wait()` upon `FIRST_EXCEPTION` detection, but the futures aren't responding to cancellation instructions:

```py
from concurrent.futures import wait, FIRST_EXCEPTION

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    futures = []
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t1"))
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t2"))
    futures.append(executor.submit(foo, "t3"))

    done, not_done = wait(futures, return_when=FIRST_EXCEPTION)
    for future in not_done:
        print("Cancelling: " + str(future))
        future.cancel()

    for future in futures:
        print(future.result())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to end all tasks in a ThreadPoolExecutor if one of them can throw an exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64946791/how-to-end-all-tasks-in-a-threadpoolexecutor-if-one-of-them-can-throw-an-excepti)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I more or less tried to use the logic demonstrated in that post, but I couldn't cancel the futures or set an exception for them so that they halt execution. I'll edit my question to share the attempt. @MauriceMeyer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For my understanding, you need the following code skeleton for your work. Notice that task2 waits 5 seconds before raising an exception so that it is easier to observe the behavior of code.

```
import threading
import time
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor

flag = False
flagLock = threading.Lock()


def foo(name):
    global flag
    print("Started task: " + name)
    if name == "t2":
        time.sleep(5)
        flagLock.acquire()
        flag = True
        flagLock.release()
        raise Exception("Forced fail")
    for i in range(5):
        flagLock.acquire()
        if flag:
            flagLock.release()
            return "One of the tasks failed, bailing out: " + name
        print("Running task: " + name)
        flagLock.release()
        time.sleep(1)
    flagLock.acquire()
    if flag:
        flagLock.release()
        return "Loops are done but bailing out anyway: " + name
    else:
        flagLock.release()
        return "Completed task: " + name


if __name__ == '__main__':

    with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(foo, "t1"), executor.submit(foo, "t2"), executor.submit(foo, "t3")]

        for future in futures:
            print(future.result())
```

Basically what the above code does is keeping a boolean called `flag` and checking it at every critical step of the job. Whenever the problematic job is to raise an exception, flag is set so that every other job knows that they should stop.

In addition, we need to protect this flag with a lock or semaphore so that multiple threads doesn't access it at the same time causing obsolete information to be fetched. If you are unfamiliar with the locks/semaphores, I would highly suggest you to study it well, and only then use it so that you won't get in trouble with deadlocks or equally nasty problems.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'll try this right away!

Comment: Works perfectly. But I think this is limited to tasks that can frequently check on the flag (e.g. this timer).

Comment: Multi-threaded tasks require special attention when the matter is their synchronization, I recommend you to study and practice well. It is one of the harder concepts on software development and requires special attention, so that you can solve tasks like this one and the more complex ones.